# Youtube api Search Video + Get Video Views in 1 api Request only

Tags: javascript, api, youtube-api

I currently have this logic to Search Videos

```
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelType=any&maxResults=20&pageToken=${Page}&q=${Value}&type=video&videoType=any&key=MyKey
```

But I also wanted to get Video statistics, I know  how to get it with another API request like this

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=S3YnYrcD1sQ&key=Mykey
```

But I wanted if I could Search Videos and get the video statistics with that search response only. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API Key is being shown on the end of the second link!
Edit the link for your own good :)

Regarding the question I don't think it's possible as of the moment due to restrictions of the youtube api.
You'll need to parse the first request and then send the second one with the video id.

Comment: Ya I Just realized, I have edited the Q. Thanks for the answer